# How to create a heartbeat helper that will then call a error page in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, timer

### EDIT:  Added AlarmManager code that is not working

I have a GPS based application that runs on the GPS event every second. Every activity  implements LocationListener and every location listener calls a helper class that does a bunch of stuff (once a second). What I want it for the screen to go red if more than 1 second goes by without a GPS event (say 5 seconds).  Here is some pseudo code:

Here are functions in a helper class

```
static long heartBeatTimer;

static public void filter(speed){
     //this routine is called once a second unless error   
    ....
    heartBeatTimer = System.nanoTime();
    ....
}

static public void heartBeat(){
    //This routine gets called on app launch and runs forever
    While (day != night){
        if (System.nanoTime() - heartBeatTimer > 5000000000) {
            // This is incorrect, I want to go to an ErrorActivity.  Doesn't work
            // Can this be done from a helper class????
            Intent target = new Intent(this, ErrorActivity.class);
            startActivity(target);
        }
    }
}
```

There are really two questions here.  My heartBeat activity would be all consuming of resources so there must be a better way to do that.  Second, once the heartBeat times out, how can I go to my error activity.

Nothing I try even begins to work.

I have tried using the AlarmManager but this code compiles but crashes with a null pointer exception.

```
PendingIntent p = setScreenRed();
p.cancel();//or p.cancel();, i am not sure
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this pseudo code:

```
if(GPS == true){
    doGSPstuff();
    PendingIntent p = setScreenRed();
    alarmManager.cancel(p);//or p.cancel();, i am not sure
    alarmManager.set(5000, p);
}
```

Basicly it (re)sets the alarmManager every time it get the gps.
If there is no gps it won't reset the alarmManager and it will run after 5 seconds.

Comment: This looks very helpful.  alarmManager looks like just what I need.    But would I have to put this in each of my 50 activities (they all run locationListener and call the helper)?  Is it possible to put something in the single helper function that all the activities already call?  I think I could put the alarm there but how can I cause the application to switch activities from the helper class?  Is that possible?

Comment: Is there a reason for implementing the listener in each activity? Why not using a service?

Comment: Well, that is the way I did it and I figure something has to be in each activity to listen so might as well be the locationListener.  That is to say, I don't see a reason to change it as I want really good timing information.  The filter is common in a helper so that is not repeated and has continuity between activities.  The question here would be the same however.  How to get to a new activity from a helper rather than from another activity.

Comment: Maybe you can create another interface for it

Comment: What do you mean by "it" and can you explain what you mean by create another interface?

Comment: A interface is a class that you can implement, like locationlistener

Comment: Again, it is probably way easyer to create a service that imlements locationlistener. And bind it to your activies. You should really consider this option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It is working and basically all done and has been working this way for a year.  I am sure I should have done what you are suggesting but I don't see a reason to change it at this point.  I am trying to get the alarmmanager to work and will post the code that crashes.